# Can't install allennlp 0.5.0 in Colab

Tags: python, allennlp, elmo

I want to use ElmoEmbedder from Elmo.

Requirements:
Python 3.6 - lower versions of Python do not work
AllenNLP 0.5.1 - to compute the ELMo representations
Keras 2.2.0 - For the creation of BiLSTM-CNN-CRF architecture

When i install allennlp 0.5.0, i got error like this.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==0.4.0 (from allennlp) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1) ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==0.4.0
```

So i install the torch 0.4.0 but it gave me another error like this

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==0.4.0 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1) ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==0.4.0
```

So, how can i install allennlp 0.5.0?

Comment: Could you please specify what command you used to install the library

Comment: @NovusEdge 
`! pip install allennlp==0.5.0`

Comment: This is a duplicate of `https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/issues/5233`.